# What guarantees are there about the contents of static libraries?

Tags: c++, c, static-libraries

On every platform I've used, static libraries are "just" archives of object files along with some metadata (in some format - the point is they are a collection of object files).

Is there some standard that requires that object files be recoverable from static archives (ie. can they always be "unpacked")? If not, is there some platform whose static libraries forget which objects were placed within them?

Comment: The benefit of individually extractible object files is that when linking through a static lib, only the actually needed object files are linked in. It is possible to merge object files into one & then pack it into a static lib, but then you'd lose that nice property of being able to link in only what's needed .

Comment: (-fdata-sections+-ffunction-sections can provide + the garbage collect option on linkers provide a similar functionality on symbol-based rather than object-file granularity, but there should be, I hear, some code size/code quality advantages to keeping related symbols in a single object file without using those -f* options)

Comment: To the extent that POSIX defines the interface to `ar`, there is a standard.  Platforms could deviate from that, but POSIX-based systems are unlikely to do so.

Comment: Note that the cat program allows me to add anything to the end of a static library file that won't be recoverable by ar or other library tools.  If your question is about security, there isn't any.

Comment: As far as C++ is concerned, that kind of details is mostly not standardized. In fact, to ensure that your library is compatible, you might even need to ensure that same options were used to compile them. That why, often when one buy some libraries, he get many libraries variations (debug/release, 32/64 bit, static/dynamic linking...)